# Issues with LDAP plugin for Tuleap Community Edition

Tags: docker, ldap, tuleap

That’s my LDAP configuration

```
$sys_ldap_server_common_name = 'Active Directory';
$sys_ldap_server = 'ldap://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$sys_ldap_server_type = 'ActiveDirectory';
$sys_ldap_dn     = 'OU=XXXXXXX,OU=XXXXXX,DC=XXXXXXX,DC=de';
$sys_ldap_bind_dn = 'CN=XXXXXXXX,OU=XXXXXXXX,OU=XXXXXXXX,OU=XXXXXXX,OU=XXXXXXXXX,DC=XXXXXXX,DC=de';
$sys_ldap_bind_passwd = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$sys_ldap_uid   = 'sAMAccountName';
$sys_ldap_eduid = 'sAMAccountName';
$sys_ldap_cn    = 'cn';
$sys_ldap_mail  = 'mail';
$sys_ldap_people_dn     = 'OU=XXXXXXXS,OU=XXXXXXX,OU=XXXXXXXX,DC=XXXXXXXXX,DC=de';
$sys_ldap_search_user='(|(sAMAccountName=%words%)(cn=%words%)(mail=%words%))';
$sys_ldap_default_user_status = 'A';
$sys_ldap_svn_auth = 0;
$sys_ldap_daily_sync = 1;
$sys_ldap_daily_sync_retention_period = 15;
$sys_ldap_user_management = 1;
$sys_ldap_grp_enabled   = 0;
$sys_ldap_grp_sync_admin_notifications_enabled = "0";
$sys_ldap_grp_dn='OU=XXXXXXX,OU=XXXXXXX,OU=XXXXXXXX,OU=XXXXXX,OU=XXXXXXX,OU=XXXXXX,DC=XXXXXXXX,DC=de';
$sys_ldap_grp_search_scope = 'subtree';
$sys_ldap_grp_cn        = 'name';
$sys_ldap_grp_member    = 'member';
$sys_ldap_grp_uid       = 'sAMAccountName';
$sys_ldap_grp_oc    = 'group';
$sys_ldap_user_oc    = 'person';
$sys_ldap_threshold_users_suspension = 1;
$search_depth = 'subtree';
```

The configuration is correct, but it doesn't work.

It's not showing me any errors and that's what it's showing me in `ldap_syslog` but still fails.

That’s the message :

```
2024-03-08T10:15:11+00:00 [73311] [debug] Bound to LDAP server: ldap://XXXXXXXXXX.de
2024-03-08T10:15:11+00:00 [73311] [debug] LDAP search success OU=XXXXXXX,OU=XXXXX,DC=XXXXXX,DC=XXXXXX (|(sAMAccountName=admin)(cn=admin)(mail=admin)) *** SCOPE: 1 *** ATTRIBUTES: mail, cn, sAMAccountName, sAMAccountName, dn
```

I need to find the error because I cannot go any further.